# CakePHP HTTPS Secure payment form

Tags: forms, cakephp, ssl, https, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3 we have a booking system for hotel rooms. A check-availability form should bring the user to a secure payment page (https://secure.domain.com/bookings/payment). After making the payment, the user gets a confirmation page (secured is also ok), but from here, any links in our header/footer should take the user back to the non-secured domain (http://domain.com).

Currently we have our SSL UCC Cert set up for the domains https://secure.domain.com and https://domain.com. We have also hard coded the check-availability form to run the action https://secure.domain.com/bookings/payment. Thus, we can get the user to get in to the HTTPS secured area, but not back out unless we hard code all our links in that section.

Cake's security component is quite confusing and thus I am looking for the best solution to make this happen.

Can Cake's Security component be used for HTTPS payment pages, make life easier, and keep the code more CakePHP standardized? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the example from http://techno-geeks.org/2009/03/using-the-security-component-in-cakephp-for-ssl/ but found it problematic. I ended up adding the following to my app_controller.php.

The code below redirects HTTPS to www.example.com and HTTP to example.com. If a user is logged in (see `$loggedUser`), it forces HTTPS for every connection.

```
// Pages requiring a secure connection.
$secureItems = array();

// beforeFilter
function beforeFilter() {
    // Your logic...    
    $this->__checkSSL();
}

/**
 * Check SSL connection.
 */
function __checkSSL() {
    /** Make sure we are secure when we need to be! **/
    if (empty($this->loggedUser)) {
        if (in_array($this->action, $this->secureItems) && !env('HTTPS')) {
            $this->__forceSSL();
        } 

        if (!in_array($this->action, $this->secureItems) && env('HTTPS')) {
            $this->__unforceSSL();
        }
    } else {
        // Always force HTTPS if user is logged in.
        if (!env('HTTPS')) {
            $this->__forceSSL();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Redirect to a secure connection
 * @return unknown_type
 */
function __forceSSL() { 
    if (strstr(env('SERVER_NAME'), 'www.')) {
        $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
    } else {
        $this->redirect('https://www.' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here); 
    }
}

/**
 * Redirect to an unsecure connection
 * @return unknown_type
 */
function __unforceSSL() {
    if (strstr(env('SERVER_NAME'), 'www.')) {
        $server = substr(env('SERVER_NAME'), 4);
        $this->redirect('http://' . $server . $this->here);
    } else {
        $this->redirect('http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a pretty good way to go: http://techno-geeks.org/2009/03/using-the-security-component-in-cakephp-for-ssl/ so you won't even have to hard code anything.